# How can I clear the console window after grep fills the screen?

Tags: command-line, grep

Is there a way to clear up what is displayed on the shell console (in ubuntu linux) in just a single key or two? When I get flood of lines from `grep` and that exceeds the height of the window, I want to quickly scroll back to the position where I typed the command after the prompt. I can do so if I had opened a fresh terminal before I type the command, and just go to the initial position. But if keep using the same terminal window, I have to manually find the position. `Ctrl+l` is not an answer because it just scrolls, and the contents of the terminal remains. I cannot use `less` because the colored output of `grep` does not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually stick with using less - try this:

```
grep --color=always foo * | less -r
```

That will tell grep to ignore that its output is being piped, and the "-r" on less tells it to pass through raw control characters, which in this case are the color codes.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work. Is it interfering with other options? I did `grep -nrI --color=always`

Comment: Hm, I did: `grep -nrI --color=always foo *  | less -r` and it worked the same, showing colors in less.  This was using bash as a shell with TERM set as 'xterm'

Comment: I am using gnome terminal. Do you use that terminal?

Comment: I just tried it in gnome-terminal, the XFCE terminal, and Konsole and it worked in all three. Maybe try with '-R' instead of '-r' on less? That tells it to only accept only ANSI color codes. Maybe some other misc control characters are sneaking through the output of grep.  If that does not work, I'm not sure what else would be causing the colors to get eaten.  BTW, I am testing this with an up-to-date installation of 10.10 in case versions are the culprit here.

Comment: I did work. Actually, in my `.bashrc`, I had `grep` aliased to `grep -nrI --color-always` and `less` aliased to `less -r`, and typing the combination of `grep` and `less` with a pipe on the console did not work, but when I typed the whole line that you gave me directly in the terminal, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If the console gets jammed/full then:

- `reset` will clear and reset the state.  You can also cause this to be sent via the magic sequence <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `clear` if you just want to clear the screen; you might combine it with the output you're after: `clear ; grep -r …`

(BTW, `reboot` is a separate command, so don't worry about accidentally rebooting your machine by using `clear` or `reset`!).